# Embedding preference orders in 2D Euclidean space

Tags: matrices, game-theory, dimension-theory-analysis, voting-theory

**PROBLEM**

I have a set of candidates $C=\{c_1,c_2,...,c_m\}$ and a set of voters $V=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$. Each voter ranks all of the candidates (e.g. $v_1: c_1 \succ c_2 \succ c_3 \succ \dots \succ c_m$).

Now I would like to embed both voters and candidates in a 2D Euclidean space.
Each voter and each candidate should be represented as a single point (therefore, I will have $m+n$ points).

**MY IDEA**

First, we create a neighborhood matrix based on voters' preference orders. Then, we use some algorithm (e.g. PCA) to reduce the dimensions.
Finally, we add candidates' points as weighted average of all voters.

**QUESTION**

Although my method is giving satisfying results, I am very curious about some known methods. I searched in Google and Google Scholar but I cannot find anything interesting enough. Can you recommend me where I can search for known solutions to this problem?

Comment: What property are you trying to optimize when you reduce to 2d?

Comment: I want to visualization the data and it is said that voters preferences in political context usually more or less resemble 2d space.

Comment: "The analysis reveals that the underlying political landscapes ... are inherently multidimensional and cannot be reduced to a single left-right dimension, or even to a two-dimensional space. ... From this representation, lower-dimensional projections can be considered which help with the visualization of the political space as resulting from an aggregation of voters' preferences. ... Even though the method aims to obtain a representation with as few dimensions as possible, we still obtain representations with four dimensions or more." https://doi.org/10.1016/j.electstud.2015.04.003

Comment: (But for ease of understanding we can pretend that it's 2D.)